# how to use .htaccess for URL rewriting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I have a wordpress website installed in blog/ folder on my server. And it can be accessible via domain.com/blog

But I need access it from domain.com/ with keeping my existing app from this folder run as it is. On root I have installed cakephp 2. Cakephp is used to run apps with its subdomains like below:

- abc.domain.com
- xyz.domain.com

I want them to run as it is with wordpress website on root.

What will be the entry in .htaccess file to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's little difficult to manage in .htaccess but you can do in WordPress coding.

it can be done in the two-step

Step 1: on your root create index.php with below content

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php' ); /** here blog is place as your folder name */
```

Step 2 : now change "domain.com" to "domain.com/blog" in your database ( for this download sql > open & edit for replace > upload new sql ).

**Now your full site runs on the domain.com URL but files are called from the "blog" folder.**

Comment: I already have cakephp's index.php, does this impact my cakephp's code.

Comment: Yes, it's affected.
As you mentioned, "But I need access it from domain.com/". So, on single domain url (domain.com) you can not run two webapp.